# How to compute a derivative of Gibbs potential that is not in his natural variables

Tags: thermodynamics, potential

I'm asken to compute $\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}$.

I start using the definition of dG:

$$dG=-SdT+Vdp+\mu dN$$

$$dG=-\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{p,N}dT+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\right)_{T,N}dp+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\right)_{T,p}dN$$

If we want to compute the derivative at N,S=constant, can we say that:

$$\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}=V\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial p}\right)-S\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}=V-S\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}$$

Is this legit?

Or we have to take $\left(\frac{\partial Vdp}{\partial p}\right)_{S,N}$ and do the product derivation?

Comment: Your formulas are correct.

Comment: But the calculation is correct?

Comment: In my opinion, your calculation is correct.

Comment: The analysis is correct so far.  But you need to figure out how to express that partial derivative of T with respect to P at constant S (in terms of known  quantities).  To do that, you need to start by expressing dS in terms of dT and dP.